# How do I use a counter in jMeter that increments each time it is invoked?

Tags: jmeter

Essentially, I'd like to have a counter in my load test that is user specific (each user gets their own counter that is initialized at 1) but is incremented each time it is invoked throughout test execution.

In other words, I'd like the following behavior out of my counter:

Request 1:

```
<item position="${POSITION_CTR}"... >      //Counter is 1
<item position="${POSITION_CTR}"... >      //Counter is 2 despite same request
```

Request 2:

```
<item position="${POSITION_CTR}"... >      //Counter is 3
```

Request 3:

```
<item position="${POSITION_CTR}"... >      //Counter is 4
```

I have attempted to use the __counter(TRUE, POSITION_CTR) function. Unfortunately, this results in a value of "1" no matter how many times I call it. I considered using a BeanShell Post processor to programmatically increment the counter value after each request, but then a request that uses the counter twice (which should be unique) will have identical counter values.

I also attempted to use a Counter (Config Element) but seemed to have the same issue as with __counter(). Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with __setProperty() in "BeanShell PostProcessor" to increment the values. But be careful, it will reflect to all the threads in Test plan.

For example, use below in BeanShell PostProcessor:

```
__setProperty("counter", "${__javaScript(${__property(counter)} + 1}
```

You can also try using var.put as below:

```
vars.put("counter", "${__javaScript(${counter} + 1}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. According to the jMeter docs:

Properties are not the same as variables. Variables are local to a thread; properties are common to all threads, and need to be referenced using the __P or __property function.

So I don't think properties are the right approach for my use case. I need each user to have their own counter. As I mentioned in the original post, the problem with using a beanshell postprocessor is that if I use the counter variable two or more times in one request, the counter will only be incremented once, and the counter will be identical in all cases.